# how user uploaded images & files are handled for their viewing in a Multiuser web application?

Tags: php, web-applications, file-upload

I'm a beginner/ intermediate PHP MySQL developer.

Planning to create a Multiuser Web application with Yii or Codeigniter, were users have their own private and public area. They will be able to upload photos and/or files to be accessible via web(docs. etc.)

I'm kind of concerned about the optimum way the files are stored.
How do those multisite/user websites(wordpress, blogger, facebook) do it?

I've thought in the following option but I have no idea if is the way is done by the industry:

Essentially we'd use 3 names(original and 2 new ones) for any user uploaded file

1. User uploads a file(image, doc, etc.), we rename the file and store it in a folder and save the original name in a DB with other file attributes
2. For showing back the file we'd use a 3rd. new name on the fly

This way, only owner knows the original name and no one knows the physical file name.

- Is this the way is done or is there a simpler way?
- Is it possible to show a file with a "virtual" name/path without file renaming or any images being recreated and no increasing the process time? or PHP has a native way to "not showing" actual file names to the Browsers?
- How would a user share a file using a web address without handling the real file name?
- Even though no one is suppose to know the physical name of the files, can someone "search" or locate the files via web?, like google or any other savvy interested user?

thank you

Comment: Have you considered storing files in DB? That might be a better option.

Comment: there are going to be some hundred of thousands of files, I understand file system is better for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You could quite simply use .htaccess to rewrite the URL's for the image paths, or instead hash the folder and file names.

Storage depends on the amount of files you'll be working with. Large companies like facebook etc work from hundreds (or more!) servers and have quite specialist methods of storage etc.

For a regular web app, simple file or database storage would probably suffice.

Comment: thank you, maybe I mistaken but is there even the need to worry about showing the actual file name? I mean, as long as the user doesn't rename it directly I can't see any problem accessing the file directly right?

Comment: I guess it depends on how sensitive the files are really. If it will bite you in the ass if someone could guess the file name and download it, hash them - if not, then just keep the regular file names.